# RxJS Unit Testing: what's the functionality of the callback passed to TestScheduler

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs

I'm trying to use `TestScheduler` to write unit test for my RxJs functions. There are many posts related to it, and I'm following this post : https://medium.com/@kevinkreuzer/marble-testing-with-rxjs-testing-utils-3ae36ac3346a

There is one confusing point for the following part:

**[image: strong text]**

I don't understand why we need to pass the callback function into `TestScheduler` constructor. In the post, it mentioned that it is `assertDeppEqual function which tells the TestScheduler how to compare values. The methods used to compare values depends on your testing framework.`

But this explanation is not clear for me. I don't figure out what's the relationship between this function and the  actual test logic we write, for example the following case:

[image]

in the above case, it assert that `expectObservable().toBe()`. what's the relationship between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to see what [`expectObservable(observable, subscriptionMarbles)`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/54d5a81158a377c5f1114fb111f76860e3cdf6c7/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L123) and [`run(callback)`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/54d5a81158a377c5f1114fb111f76860e3cdf6c7/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L403) methods do.

`expectObservable()` [subscribes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/54d5a81158a377c5f1114fb111f76860e3cdf6c7/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L134) to a passed `observable`. The callback methods passed to `subscribe()` method populate `actual` array (this is what you get in a callback passed to `TestScheduler` constructor).

`actual` array [gets pushed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/54d5a81158a377c5f1114fb111f76860e3cdf6c7/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L152) to `this.flushTests` array (wrapped in `flushTest` object). `flushTests` is an array of tests that have to be executed (remember, you can call multiple times `expectObservable()` or `expectSubscriptions()` methods). If you're using `run()` method (and you do based on the image), after a `run()` callback is executed, [`this.flush()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/54d5a81158a377c5f1114fb111f76860e3cdf6c7/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L422) method is called. This method *runs* your tests by [calling](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/54d5a81158a377c5f1114fb111f76860e3cdf6c7/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L188) `this.assertDeepEqual()` callback that you provided to `TestScheduler` constructor.

The `actual` and `expected` values from the `test` are passed in. `expected` is populated in the same method where `actual` is populated, [just after it](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/54d5a81158a377c5f1114fb111f76860e3cdf6c7/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L158).

So, calling `expectObservable()` only prepares and converts Observable values to something comparable (an array of `actual` and `expected` values). It is your responsibility, as the official documentation says, to do the comparison based on the testing framework you're using.