# Angular Unit Test: how to use marble testing (rxjs/testing) to test this state management service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine-marbles, rxjs-marbles

In my angular project, I have a service, which is used for state management to share some data between components as following:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root"})
export class NameStateService {

    private _filteredNames$: Subject<Name[]> = new Subject();
    private _filteredNamesObs$: Observable<Name[]>;

    constructor() {
        this._filteredNamesObs$ = this._filteredNames$.asObservable();
    }

    public updateFilteredNames(val: Name[]): void {
        this._filteredNames$.next(val);
    }

    public get filteredNames$(): Observable<BillingAccount[]> {
        return this._filteredNamesObs$;
    }
}
```

the state management is based on subject and observable, which is typical usage in rxjs world.

And For the unit test for this service, I want to use the marble testing features suppored by `rxjs/testing` module. The solution goes as following:

```
describe("Name state service ", () => {
    let nameStateService: NameStateService;
    let scheduler: TestScheduler;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                NameStateService
            ]
        });
        nameStateService = TestBed.get(NameStateService);
        scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => expect(actual).toEqual(expected));
    });

    it("should be created", () => {
        expect(nameStateService).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should return a valid names observables", () => {
        scheduler.run(({ cold, hot, expectObservable }) => {
            const mockNames: Name[] = [{
                title: "title1",
                group: "group1"
            }]; 
            nameStateService.updateFilteredNames(mockNames);
            expectObservable(nameStateService.filteredNames$).toBe("-b", {b: mockNames});
        });
    });
})
```

But the second unit test failed with the error: `Error: Expected $.length = 0 to equal 1.` So it means that `nameStateService.filteredNames$`, this observable has no values in its stream.

What is the issue here?

Comment: I suspect that `expectObservable(nameStateService.filteredNames$)` creates a subscription after the subject fires the events, thus it's empty.  
Try to mock the getter of `filteredNames$` and return a `hot` observable with appropriate marble diagram. Use [Spy](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html) class for mocking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your set up could be quite hard to test using RxJS marbles.

The first issue is that you're sending some stuff down the stream before subscribing to it. [Remember](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540490/1253279), `expectObservable()` synchronously subscribes to a passed observable (in your case `nameStateService.filteredNames$`). But, no data is sent there since you've already sent it by calling `nameStateService.updateFilteredNames(mockNames)`.

You could think about having these two lines change positions, but remember that this is synchronous execution environment, so doing this

```
expectObservable(nameStateService.filteredNames$).toBe("-b", {b: mockNames});
nameStateService.updateFilteredNames(mockNames);
```

wouldn't help either since `expectObservable()` would subscribe to `nameStateService.filteredNames$`, then it would read all the values, but since there's no values as you're sending them in a line after this, an `actual` array would be empty.

To avoid this, you should mock your `nameStateService.filteredNames$` observable. To do it, you could do two things, but both of them having their own issues. So, the second issue with your set up is that you could make `cold` or `hot` Observable and use them instead of `filteredNames$` Observable.

This could be achieved like this:

```
nameStateService.filteredNames$ = hot('-b', { a: mockNames });
```

but this errors with *TS2540: Cannot assign to 'filteredNames$' because it is a read-only property.* since you don't have setter for `filteredNames$`. If you'd add setter, then this would break your contract of having `this._filteredNamesObs$` as private property that is created from `this._filteredNames$` `Subject`.

The other way would be to mock `this._filteredNames$` using Jasmine spies (which is a third issue), but this set up is also having problems. What to mock? The whole `nameStateService`? In this case, you'd have to create spies for every particular property and function of the service. Or mock `nameStateService._filteredNames$` property? Or even better, `nameStateService.filteredNames$`? But mocking them would cause others to behave differently since not all of them are mocked.

So, I would suggest not using TestScheduler at all, and writing your test like this:

```js
it('should return a valid names observables', () => {
  const values: Name[][] = [];
  expect(values).toEqual([]);
  nameStateService.updateFilteredNames([{ group: 'G', title: 'Before subscribe' }]);
  expect(values).toEqual([]);

  nameStateService.filteredNames$.subscribe({
    next(names) {
      values.push(names);
    }
  });
  expect(values).toEqual([]);

  nameStateService.updateFilteredNames([{ group: 'G', title: 'After subscribe' }]);
  expect(values).toEqual([[{ group: 'G', title: 'After subscribe' }]]);
});
```

---

However, another solution could be present (if you really, really want to use marbles), you'd just have to be very careful and know what you're doing. You could change `_filteredNames$` to a `ReplaySubject`.

```
private _filteredNames$: Subject<Name[]> = new ReplaySubject();
```

This would cause any subsequent subscribers to get all the values that are sent down the stream even before subscribing to it. You'd just have to delete one char (`-` sign that is passed to `toBe` method, and your passing test would look like this:

```js
it('should return a valid names observables', () => {
  scheduler.run(({ cold, hot, expectObservable }) => {
    const mockNames: Name[] = [{
      title: 'title1',
      group: 'group1'
    }];
    nameStateService.updateFilteredNames(mockNames);
    expectObservable(nameStateService.filteredNames$).toBe('b', {b: mockNames});
  });
});
```